# How to center the column label in a table?

Tags: tables, labels, multicolumn, center

I am trying to align to the center (horizontal) the labels: "Registro" and " Datos faltantes". I used \begin(center) Registro \end(center) and \ centering(Registro), But I didn't work. Anyone could help me? Thanks

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany,spanish]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.3cm,right=2.3cm,top=2.1cm,bottom=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} % Paquetes matemáticos
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Codificación .tex
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Para insertar imágenes
\usepackage{lipsum} % Para texto falso
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified,margin=0 mm}
\caption{Características}
\footnotesize{
\begin{tabular}{p{0.6 in}p{1.3in}p{0.8in}p{0.6in}p{2.1in}}
\toprule[1.8pt] \\[-10pt]
\multirow{2}[3]{*}{\textbf{Estación}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Ubicación}}  &
\multirow{2}[3]{*}{\textbf{Profundidad}} &
\multirow{2}{*}{{\textbf{Registro}}} &
\multirow{2}[3]{*}{\textbf{Datos faltantes}}  \\[0.1cm] \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\\[-0.3cm] 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Latitud Longitud}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(m)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(mes/día/año)}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(mes/día/año)}} 
\\
\midrule[1pt] \\ [-0.4cm]
\multicolumn{5}{c}{{Nivel del mar}}\\ [0.1cm]
\hline \\ [-0.3cm]
\textsc{m. aca} $^{1}$ &  &   \centering{$ ^{4}$}  & mm/dd/aaaa &
\\[0.3cm]
\textsc{m. mzn} $^{2}$ & &   \centering{$ ^{4}$}   & mm/dd/aaaa &
\\[0.3cm]
\textsc{m. zht} $^{3}$ & &    \centering{$ ^{4}$}  & mm/dd/aaaa &
\\[0.1cm]  
\bottomrule[1pt]
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose these code simplifications with the `makecell` package:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany,spanish]{book}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[left=2.3cm,right=2.3cm,top=2.1cm,bottom=2.3cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} % Paquetes matemáticos
    \usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{graphicx} % Para insertar imágenes
    \usepackage{lipsum} % Para texto falso
    \usepackage{caption}

    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified,margin=0 mm}
    \caption{Características}
    \footnotesize{
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.6 in}p{1.3in}p{0.8in}p{0.6in}p{2.1in}}
    \toprule[1.8pt]\addlinespace[-1.5ex]
    \thead{Estación } & \thead{Ubicación \\ Latitud Longitud} & \thead{Profundidad \\ (m)}
     & \thead{Registro \\ (mes/día/año)} & \thead[t]{ \\ Datos faltantes \\ (mes/día/año)}
    \\ \midrule[1pt]%
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{{Nivel del mar}}\\ [0.1cm]
    \hline \\ [-0.3cm]
    \textsc{m. aca} $^{1}$ & & \centering{$ ^{4}$} & mm/dd/aaaa &
    \\[0.3cm]
    \textsc{m. mzn} $^{2}$ & & \centering{$ ^{4}$} & mm/dd/aaaa &
    \\[0.3cm]
    \textsc{m. zht} $^{3}$ & & \centering{$ ^{4}$} & mm/dd/aaaa &
    \\[0.1cm]
    \bottomrule[1pt]
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!

Comment: Thank you all, I have just  noticed that text within column is not center aligned. I used \centering for the first 2 columns, It worked ;in the last one It did't worked (\centering), it marked an error.  All solutions are good, I only would like to get the text aligned (centered). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Miguel: For  paragraph-like column type, youu can load the `array` package and use in the tabular preamble `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{…}`.

Answer (score 1):

- For your table you can use `tabularray` package with libraries `amsmath`, `booktabs` and `siunitx`.
- for numbers in table written as exponent I guess that they are intendent for table notes, therefore in the following MWE for table environment in used `talltblr` (which is `tabularray` equivalent for `threeparttable`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany,spanish]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.3cm,vmargin={2.1cm,2.3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb} % Paquetes matemáticos

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, siunitx}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Para insertar imágenes
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            justification=justified,
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Para texto falso

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Características}
\label{tab:?}
\centering
\small
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}
\SetTblrStyle{note}{font=\footnotesize}
\begin{talltblr}[
label=none,
note{1} = {description},
note{2} = {description},
note{3} = {description},
note{4} = {description},
                ]{
    colsep=4pt,
    colspec = {@{} Q[l, m] *{4}{X[c, m]} @{}},
    cell{3-Z}{1} = {font=\scshape}, 
    row{1} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
             }
    \toprule
Estación    & {Ubicación\\ Latitud Longitud}
                & {Profundidad\\ (m)}
                    & Registro (mes/día/año)
                        & Datos faltantes (mes/día/año)     \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=5]{c}    Nivel del mar
            &   &   &   &                                   \\
    \midrule[0.8pt]
m. aca \TblrNote{1} &   & \TblrNote{4}  & mm/dd/aaaa &      \\
m. mzn \TblrNote{2} &   & \TblrNote{4}  & mm/dd/aaaa &      \\
m. zht \TblrNote{3} &   & \TblrNote{4}  & mm/dd/aaaa &      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]